# certbot can't find challenge file

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I'm trying to add a domain to my LE certificate. Although I've added domains before, something seems to be amiss.

Specifically
`sudo certbot renew --dry-run` confirms that a renewal is possible, thus all subdomains can respond with a challenge file.

HOWEVER
`sudo certbot certonly --cert-name mysite.com --expand -d mysite.com,www.mysite.com,oldsubdomain.mysite.com,newsubdomain.mysite.com`

will return 404 for every subdomain it tries to hit.

```
Domain: oldsubdomain.mysite.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://oldsubdomain.mysite.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/QQsj9SA-tnlzRCvCK8ZrknATkqfwcr0V77d9PR9zKaE:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"
```

However, if I manually visit `http://oldsubdomain.mysite.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test`, I receive the challenge file.

(note, I can't paste http://w-w-w.mysite.com/ due to SO restrictions)

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure why the above command didn't work, but I ended up solving it by inspecting the webroots in `etc/letsencrypt/renewal/mysite.com.conf`.

The specified webroot provided the necessary validation...although based on the logs, I still can't say why the original webroot path failed.